# How can I duplicate this site/get a theme similar to this site?

Tags: themes

### How can I duplicate this site/get a theme similar to this site?

**Context**

---

So I was taking a look at this site https://highschooltutors.com.au or https://learnmate.com.au. They have features which are similar to that of Freelancer, in that you can post your own ads, but it centres more around an educational system, rather than, say, products for sale.

**Question**

---

How would I go about building a site like this on Wordpress? Is it feasible to take and edit a free ecommerce templates or would I be better off buying a theme for a freelance marketplace and trying to adapt that? How much would it cost to hire someone to make a site like this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several sites that will tell you the theme and plugins used on a WordPress site. Ask the googles/bings/ducks for "what wordpress theme is that". The results may often include paid themes that have been extensively customized, but may give you a starting point.

As for how to do it - that's a big question that depends on your skills. And how much is also a big questions - it depends on how much technical/programming knowledge you have, and how extensive you want the site to be. There is no good answer for both of those questions; and those questions are not within the scope of this site (which is probably why you got the downvotes).

There are themes/plugins that have visual drag/drop designers, so you can create your version of a theme with all the elements you want. Examples are Divi, Elementor, and others. But even those tools still require a bit of effort and knowledge (and design sense), so can be complex to use.

Overall, your question is not really a 'development' issue, and not within the scope of this site. But perhaps my answer will point you in the right direction.